# How do I reference an online image from a LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics, external-files, online

I've tried this chunk of code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{figure}
    \href{http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pachydyptes_ponderosus.jpg}
         {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture}}
\end{figure}
```

and am getting this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `picture' not found.
```

Comment: Is the `picture` file in your system? Apparently not; if your only interest is to hyper-reference the image, don't `\includegraphics` it. If you want to include it in your document, make sure that the file is in your current working directory.

Comment: easiest way would be to save the picture on your system and note the online location withing the caption or in you bibliography

Comment: I do not recommend to include such kind of pictures. Save a local copy and use it with the source from the original. If the original will be changed and you compile the document again, the result will be different